# Hardware crash on my MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, hardware, apple-hardware-test

Last Tuesday my computer crashed during a Skype meeting, it froze, the screen went black and 3 beeps started to sound in series. I googled the symptom and found out that it was related to a memory parity check problem. On Wednesday I removed the offending DIMM (left 1 "good" still working) and the computer seemed to work fine until today when the system has crashed twice with a white screen with a generic crash error in several languages. Tried the Apple hardware test (not the extensive one yet), but it reported no troubles. Does OSX store logs for crashed that I could read and/or share with you?

Any hints on diagnosing a possible hardware fail would be appreciated.

Update 05/22/2017: System crashed and rebooted, with the following output:

```
Anonymous UUID:       AB7135DC-91EA-23D8-1AA4-EA261F713210

Sat May 20 19:08:11 2017

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff802cb8380b): "vm_page_reactivate_local: count = 250, vm_page_local_count = 251\n"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3248.60.11.5.3/osfmk/vm/vm_resident.c:3708
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8038a6bab0 : 0xffffff802cad7b92 
0xffffff8038a6bb30 : 0xffffff802cb8380b 
0xffffff8038a6bb80 : 0xffffff802cb47bc2 
0xffffff8038a6bd00 : 0xffffff802cb4b99b 
0xffffff8038a6bf20 : 0xffffff802cbcc2ef 
0xffffff8038a6bfb0 : 0xffffff802cbe9ac5 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: xpcproxy

Mac OS version:
15G1510

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Tue Apr 11 16:00:51 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3248.60.11.5.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 4BE0C0F5-2855-346B-8595-18FFCE9A51DC
Kernel slide:     0x000000002c800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff802ca00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff802c900000
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 102267290093850
last loaded kext at 245116733687: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.10 (addr 0xffffff7faf890000, size 69632)
last unloaded kext at 362634995366: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10 (addr 0xffffff7faf890000, size 61440)
loaded kexts:
foo.tap 1.0
foo.tun 1.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  5.0.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  5.0.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 5.0.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 5.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   90.3
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.6f1
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.22.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   274.12
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   274.12
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1040.1.1a6
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  304.12
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport  5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.2.4
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 274.12
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.6f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.6f1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    205.11
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.9
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.4
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B15, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2,5 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.2f44
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D5358384758334D314131363030433130
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.175.1a6)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.6f1 17910, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB, 500,11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Comfort Curve Keyboard 2000
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Update 05/23/2017: just ran the full hardware test and no problems were found, bit once again I got a system crash

Update 05/24/2017: System log shared [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BznExEDmormvbFNLWkpTRUJ0aTQ).

Macbook specs:

Macbook Pro Mid 2012; 2.5GHz Core i5 Processor, 8GB RAM, Intel HD 4000, Samsung 850EVO 500GB SSD.  macOS 10.11.6 (El Capitan)

Comment: I would think perhaps running the 'extensive' test in Apple hardware test would be a good place to start. :)

Comment: After following Mac Lover's suggestion, if you can manage to boot the computer, you can use the console app to locate the system logs. There should be error/crash logs in the system.log file (you might have to scroll back to find them). It sounds like either you RAM or DIMM (the slot that holds the RAM) is having problems. If it's the RAM, I'd suggest buying replacement RAM. If it's the DIMM slot itself, that's a bigger problem.

Comment: The system.log will probably be useful. First check to make sure the log has recorded back past the time of the crash, then create a copy and post a link to it in the original question. Then comment and tag me so I get a notification to check it out

Comment: @Allan used to have 16GB, but a DIMM "died" last week, so I just have the remaining 8GB right now. No big apps are running, so I guess 8GB should be fine, but system monitor shows 6.6GB used right now

Comment: Is that 6.6 used by apps or total?  What about the (approx. 1.5GB) used by Intel HD?  If it's by apps only, you ran out of memory.

Comment: Awesome...in the meantime...clear out some of the comments so it does't get too long.  Relevant info should be in the original question.